# Как получить Image из PixelAccess

Tags: python, pil

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('sample.png')
pix = image.load()
```

Можно ли получить из pix объект Image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/reference/PixelAccess.html#pixelaccess) нельзя. Класс `PixelAccess` не имеет никаких методов, возвращаюших `Image`. Можно только попиксельно прочитать PixelAccess и назначить цвет другому изображению, но это по сути копирование изображения и стоит использовать предназначенный для этого [метод](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.copy):

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('sample.png')
image_copy = image.copy()
```